# Is Jboss 5.1.0 Password Based Encryption Secure?

Tags: security, jboss, cryptography

I am securing our our servers using password based encryption for Jboss 5.1.0.

I have read the parts of the RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898

I have read the several Jboss documents several times:

https://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html (this is for 6.0, but works with 5.1.0)

Now, let me explain my issue.

In the official JBoss document listed above, they treat "Secured Identity" encryption as if it is secure. Heck, it is in the documents. *Worse, I've seen other people ask questions on Stack Overflow on how to use this*. **This is not secure**. To make it secure, one has to write their own encryption class overriding org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule.

I was able to prove this by doing a quick google search of "Decrypt Jboss 5.1.0 Password" and the first result was a jar file that decrypted Jboss passwords using the recommended approach in the official Jboss documentation.

Enter Password Based Encryption.

Knowing I've already found a security flaw in the first approach, I am already wearing of taking advice from this documentation-- if your wrong once, your probably wrong twice. However, it seems I don't have  I must use approach 2: Password Based Encryption.

My concern is, the documentation makes me generate a 'master.password' file. I am assuming this is the derived key function mentioned in the RFC.  However, I don't know for certain.

All in all, my gut tells me this:
Your making me store a master.password on my server. The master.password file that contains the derived key function can be used by some code somewhere to simply decrypt my encrypted password. That is because I am specifying salt and iterations elsewhere in other files.

This whole process seems like a mathematical function. On my end it looks like this:

? = DerivedKeyFunction(Salt, Iterations, Password)

But for the hacker it looks like this:

EncodedPassword = DerivedKeyFunction(Salt, Iterations, ?)

I'm claim to be neither a cryptographer or a Jboss expert, but my gut tells me all a hacker needs to do is look at the Jboss source code (which is open source as far as I know) and do a little bit of reverse engineering to get the password using the server.password file.

So my question is: How secure is Password Based Encryption on Jboss (assuming the hacker gained access to the server)? Has anyone actually looked into this?

------------ **EDIT** -----------------

To clarify:
This is for JBoss to connect to our Database. This is not for an end-user to log into their user account on a web application.

JBoss uses a master.password (or server.password... its just a filename) which contains some sort of encrypted string. I'm not sure what's in here, its not well documented (or maybe it is and I just don't understand).

After the configuration is followed, a password is never entered again. I don't see how this is secure. I'm guessing I can somehow use the server.password file created in step 1 to decrypt my database password. Someone just hasn't written a convenient jar file yet. But the code is opensource, so I'm guessing the right person knows how to do this very easily.

I am sharing the steps due to the number of terrible setups I've seen people using on stack overflow. The steps are as follows:

1. From jboss/common/lib folder, Create server.password file. place in server/conf directory.:

   ```
    java -cp jbosssx.jar org.jboss.security.plugins.FilePassword <8Charactersalt> <iterationsMoreThan1000> <aLongRandomPassword> server.password
    #outputs server.password file which contains encrypted string.
   ```
2. Encrypt Database Password

   ```
    java -cp jbosssx.jar org.jboss.security.plugins.PBEUtils <8Charactersalt> <iterationsMoreThan1000> <aLongRandomPassword> <databaseConnectionPassword>
    #outputs encrypted DB Password
   ```
3. Remove Username & Password & Update Datasource XML

   ```
    <security-domain>EncryptedMySqlDbRealm</security-domain>
    <depends>jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityDomain,domain=ServerMasterPassword</depends>
   ```
4. Add Mbean To Datasource XML. it specifies the server.password file, salt and iterations.

   {CLASS}org.jboss.security.plugins.FilePassword:${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.password
   ${8Charactersalt}
   ${iterationsMoreThan1000}
5. Add Application Policy To Login Config XML. specify username, encrypted password, and datasource to encrypt. There is a 1 to 1 mapping between application policies and datasources, so if you have two datasources, it appears you need 2 application policies as well. Otherwise you get errors starting up jboss.

   ${DatabaseUsername}
         ${EncryptedPassword}
         jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=${DataSourceNameFromDatasourceXML}
         jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityDomain,domain=ServerMasterPassword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your just want to obfuscate your password.  Encrypting it just makes this a circular process:  You need to choose a password to encrypt your password that you will use to encrypt your password that you will.....

Simply Base-64 encode it.   Or some other type of (non-encrypting) encoding.

Comment: Thank you. It is misleading that it is called "Encrypting the password" when it is really just obfuscating it. Encryption and obfuscation are two entirely different things.

Comment: Still, I am happy with the password based encryption, even though it only makes it slightly more inconvenient for an attacker to deobfuscate the password.

Comment: Still, users using the secured identity with the default 'jaas is the way' and 'Blowfish' should really update their encryption/obfuscation to the method I outlined above

Answer (score 0):

First, a cavet: I know nothing of the JBoss system to which you are referring.  But I'm fairly sure the system is **not** asking you to "store a master.password on my server."  However, I am familiar enough with encryption to offer this explanation:

You want to store some plain-text data and protect it with a password.  So, you ask a user for a password, encrypt it, and store the encrypted text (call this "cipher-text") and then *discard* the password.  When the user wants to retrieve it, you ask for a password and then decrypt the "Cipher-Text".  If the password is correct you will get back the original Plain-Text.

An encryption (and decryption) process requires a Key.  This is numeric value, not a password.   So, you need a way to **derive** a Key-value from some text Pass-Phrase.   The `DerivedKeyFunction` performs this action.   The returned result **is not** an Encoded Password.   It is a Key value that is passed to the encryption/decryption process.

So, you ask the user for a Pass-Phrase, then call `DerivedKeyFunction` to get a Key-value, then encrypt the Plain-Text into Cipher-Text (using the **Key**), store the resulting Cipher-Text and then **discard the Pass-Phrase and the Key**.
And to decrypt, you ask for the Pass-Phrase, re-derive the Key, and then decrypt.

Basically, the `DerivedKeyFunction` is a Hash function (or process); you use it to "convert" the Pass-Phrase into a numeric value that can be used by the encrypt process.

Now, you will note the other two parameters to the `DerivedKeyFunction`: "Salt" and "Iterations".  These are required to increase the difficulty of an attack on your data.   "Iterations" (obviously) specifies the number of times to re-hash the Pass-Phrase.  And the "Salt" injects a random number into this iterative process.
Hopefully, you see now that these are two values that **you will need to store** with the Cipher-Text.   Any time you want to derive the Key from your Pass-Phrase, you must do it the same way each time; that means iterating the same number of times *and* injecting the same "Salt" value.

So, now your process is:

1) Pick a random Salt value (yes, a random number).

2) Decide on iteration count, lets say for example 100,000. (this should be a big number, so `DerivedKeyFunction` takes a long time; explanation in a moment)

3) Ask the user for a Pass-Phrase.

4) Call `DerivedKeyFunction` handing it the Pass-Phrase, the random Salt value, and 100,000.   This returns a Key-value (implied by those 3 parameters).

5) Encrypt Plain-Text into Cipher-Text using the Key-value.

6) Store the Cipher-Text **and** the Salt value **and** the iteration count (100,000)

7) Discard the Pass-Phrase and Key-value.

To decrypt:

1) Ask for the Pass-Phrase.

2) Call `DerivedKeyFunction` handing it the Pass-Phrase, the **stored** Salt value, and the **stored** iteration count.   If the Pass-Phrase is correct, then the  same (correct) Key-value will be returned.

3) Decrypt the Cipher-Text into Plain-Text using the Key-value.

Ok, so why choose a large number for the iteration count?  Well, an attacker is will simply just spin around trying password after password until they successfully decrypt the the Cipher-Text.  But they have to call `DerivedKeyFunction` with each attempt they make.  **And**, they must use the correct **Salt** value and **Iteration count** that you used when you encrypted the data.  And, yes, since you had to store them for your use, an attacker will know what they are; but they still have to call `DerivedKeyFunction` over-and-over.  So you should see that the higher you make the iteration count, the less the number of attempts-per-second an attacker can try.

Although you didn't mention it, when using CBC (Cipher-Block-Chain) type encryption algorithms, there is another parameter called the IV or Initialization Vector.  This value is an input to the encryption/decryption as a companion to the Key.  As it pertains to the above processes, treat it as an extension of the Key:  The `DerivedKeyFunction` that is used should provide both a Key-value and an IV-value.  And, as with the Key-value, the IV-value is never stored and is discarded at the same points that the Key-value is discarded.

Comment: Your answer has great information in it. Thank you. However, I think I need to explain what the cryptography is being used for.

I am encrypting the password for the connection to the database. Users aren't actually asked for any password, JBoss is the user. Everybody says 'passwords in XML are bad', but the solutions I am finding seem to just make it annoying, not impossible to decrypt the password.

The method you are suggesting makes sense, if a user is asked a password (such as a login form to a website). But Jboss isn't asked to enter a password, it just starts up and is connected.

Comment: Alright...I assume you're going to update your question....  But, the process I described is very generalized (i.e., not specific to JBoss or any other framework or programming language/system).  No matter what your "Plain-Text" is, and no matter what your storage system is, and no matter your reasons for protecting it with encryption, you will need to follow the steps I outlined.

Comment: It sounds to me that you just want to obfuscate the password.  Your going to chase your tail if you encrypt it.  That is, you will need to choose a password to do the encryption of the JBoss password and then store it somewhere (since, as you say, no one is asked for a password).  A very circular problem there.  Maybe just Base-64 encode the JBoss password your going to use? (Or some other obscure encoding).  An attacker would need both the text representation (the encoded) version of the password **and** the encoding algorithm you choose to use.

Comment: It should be obvious, and maybe you don't want to hear it, but the price of the convenience significantly reduces (if not destroys) the security of this JBoss system.  Just say'n.

Comment: I guess one other option would be to just select a Key-value to encrypt your password and then store that number in your XML.   Remember, the Key-value (number) **is** the actual "password" for the encryption.   The `DerivedKeyFunction` step is used to help us poor humans:  so we can use a text phrase as our password and not some gigantic number.   So, you would simply select a (big) number, store that in your XML and only call encrypt/decrypt.  You wouldn't need to call `DerivedKeyFunction` at all.....

Comment: ...but please see that this is probably an over-the-top method.   You're just looking for a way to obfuscate your JBoss password.   Encryption isn't adding anything here since an attacker will "know" the password. (the Key-value you store in your XML)